# Why should I update the bootloader when flashing custom ROM?

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, bootloader

I have a Realme GT Neo2. The developer behind the custom ROMs says it's required to flash some firmware `Firmware_EU_F.04_RM-Warning.zip`. Inside the archive, there's an `abl.img` file which I believe is going to replace or update the bootloader.

Why even touch the bootloader? Imagine flashing a corrupted archive and ending up with a bricked, unrestorable phone.

A list of files inside the archive:

```
├── META-INF
│   └── com
│       ├── android
│       │   ├── metadata
│       │   ├── ota_md5.csv
│       │   └── otacert
│       └── google
│           └── android
│               ├── removable_images.txt
│               ├── update-binary
│               └── updater-script
├── firmware-update
│   ├── BTFM.img
│   ├── DRIVER.img
│   ├── abl.img
│   ├── aop.img
│   ├── cdt_engineering.img
│   ├── cmnlib.img
│   ├── cmnlib64.img
│   ├── devcfg.img
│   ├── dpAP.img
│   ├── dspso.img
│   ├── dtbo.img
│   ├── hyp.img
│   ├── imagefv_ddr4.img
│   ├── imagefv_ddr5.img
│   ├── keymaster64.img
│   ├── modem.img
│   ├── oppo_sec.img
│   ├── qupv3fw.img
│   ├── splash.img
│   ├── static_nvbk.img
│   ├── tz.img
│   ├── vbmeta.img
│   ├── vbmeta_system.img
│   ├── vbmeta_vendor.img
│   ├── xbl_config_ddr4.img
│   ├── xbl_config_ddr5.img
│   ├── xbl_ddr4.img
│   └── xbl_ddr5.img
└── system
```

Comment: For firmware images provided by Google for their phones it is not uncommon to include updated bootloader images, but for a custom ROM it is indeed unusual. May be the new bootloader disables a feature like dm-verity?

Comment: there is also version binding to android. downgrade protection sometimes forces update of older insecure binaries